# Fade out last created div with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a form that creates a new div with text and i need every new div to appear with fade in effect. i managed to achieve that with css :last-child, but when i remove one of the div's and recreate the existing divs on the page the effect turning on again. any way to remove the ID with fade in effect while i recreate the rest of the divs on the page? cant use jquery. couldnt find a solution that will work for my situation. any help will be appreciated. thank you.

```js
var myTasks = [];
draw_note();

function create_new_task() {
 let task_field = document.getElementById('task_field').value;
 let new_task = {
 task : task_field,
}
    
    myTasks.push( new_task );
    draw_note();
    document.querySelector('.task_form').reset();
  
    return false; 
}

function draw_note() {
    document.querySelector('.task_table').innerHTML = '';
    let task_container = document.createElement('div');
    task_container.id = 'my-tasks';
    task_container.classList.add("mx-3", "my-4", "row", "justify-content-start");
  
for( let i=0; i < myTasks.length; i++ ) {
    let body_note = document.createElement('div');
    body_note.id = 'fadeIn';
    body_note.classList.add("note_style", "col-6", "my-3", "mx-2", "p-3");
        
    let task_info = document.createElement('div');
    task_info.innerText = myTasks[i].task;
    body_note.appendChild(task_info);
  
    let td_delete = document.createElement('div');
    body_note.appendChild(td_delete);
        
    let delete_button = document.createElement('button');
    delete_button.innerText = 'remove';
    delete_button.setAttribute('onclick', 'delete_note(' + i + ')');

    td_delete.appendChild(delete_button);

    task_container.appendChild(body_note);
}
 
  document.querySelector('.task_table').appendChild(task_container);

}

function delete_note( the_key ) { 
  myTasks.splice(the_key,1); 
  draw_note();
}
```

```css
.note_style {
    background-color: #D0D5D7;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 250px;
    max-height: 250px;
}


#fadeIn:last-child{
    animation: fadein 1.5s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
  <div class="col-12 myform">

  
 <form action="" method="post" class ="text-center px-5 task_form" onSubmit="return create_new_task()">
  <div class="form-group">
  <label></label>
  <textarea class="form-control" id="task_field" name="task_field" rows="5" placeholder="Enter task"></textarea>
 </div>
                         

<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success mybtn mt-3 mr-1 mb-4"  value="Add task">
<input type="reset" class="btn btn-success resetbtn mt-3 ml-1 mb-4" value="Reset">
 </form>

</div> 
</div> 

<div class="task_table"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few changes I added to implement what you want:

- I added `fadeout` animation and used it in a new CSS class `remove-element` that will be added once user click on delete task.
- the class will be added to the removed element after that a [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) function execute delete() function after 1 second which is the time for the fadeout animation.
- note that I change the add task function to have a flag that will be used to check if the last element should be animated based on being a new task added or the re-draw function executed after delete task.

---

Here is a working snippet:

```js
var myTasks = [];
draw_note(true);

function create_new_task() {
 let task_field = document.getElementById('task_field').value;
 let new_task = {
 task : task_field,
}
    
    myTasks.push( new_task );
    draw_note(true);
    document.querySelector('.task_form').reset();
  
    return false; 
}

function draw_note(addAnimation) {
    document.querySelector('.task_table').innerHTML = '';
    let task_container = document.createElement('div');
    task_container.id = 'my-tasks';
    task_container.classList.add("mx-3", "my-4", "row", "justify-content-start");
  
for( let i=0; i < myTasks.length; i++ ) {
    let body_note = document.createElement('div');
    body_note.id = 'fadeIn';
    body_note.classList.add("note_style", "col-6", "my-3", "mx-2", "p-3");
        
    let task_info = document.createElement('div');
    task_info.innerText = myTasks[i].task;
    task_info.setAttribute('id', 'element-' + i);
    if(i === myTasks.length -1 && addAnimation) {
      task_info.classList.add('last-element');
    }
    body_note.appendChild(task_info);
  
    let td_delete = document.createElement('div');
    body_note.appendChild(td_delete);
        
    let delete_button = document.createElement('button');
    delete_button.innerText = 'remove';
    delete_button.setAttribute('onclick', 'delete_note(' + i + ')');

    td_delete.appendChild(delete_button);

    task_container.appendChild(body_note);
}
 
  document.querySelector('.task_table').appendChild(task_container);

}

function delete_note( the_key ) {
  document.getElementById('element-' + the_key).classList.add('remove-element');
  setTimeout(function() {
    myTasks.splice(the_key,1);
    draw_note(false);
  }, 1000)
}
```

```css
.note_style {
    background-color: #D0D5D7;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 250px;
    max-height: 250px;
}


.last-element {
    animation: fadein 1.5s;
}

.remove-element {
    animation: fadeout 1s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}

@keyframes fadeout {
    from {
        opacity:1;
    }
    to {
        opacity:0;
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
  <div class="col-12 myform">

  
 <form action="" method="post" class ="text-center px-5 task_form" onSubmit="return create_new_task()">
  <div class="form-group">
  <label></label>
  <textarea class="form-control" id="task_field" name="task_field" rows="5" placeholder="Enter task"></textarea>
 </div>
                         

<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success mybtn mt-3 mr-1 mb-4"  value="Add task">
<input type="reset" class="btn btn-success resetbtn mt-3 ml-1 mb-4" value="Reset">
 </form>

</div> 
</div> 

<div class="task_table"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help! this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Glad that it helped :)